# Where does lightdm store its desktop environment settings?

Tags: debian, lightdm

As you can see in the image below, on login lightdm has a certain desktop environment pre-selected, and also has the option to switch over to others.
[image: lightdm options]
Where in the file system is this information stored? I do not see it in the `/etc/lightdm` folder, nor in `/usr/share/lightdm`, and from  a cursory glance /etc/X11 doesn't contain it either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Debian and derivatives, display managers are supposed to offer to the user the session types described in `.desktop` files in `/usr/share/xsessions` and `/usr/share/wayland-sessions`. (Source: empirical observation and [this thread](https://lists.debian.org/debian-devel/2022/01/msg00353.html), I can't find the authoritative document.) Each session manager or window manager package is supposed to drop a file in these directories.

Display managers may offer additional choices, for example if they have a special affinity to some particular session manager, or if they have a guest session feature. And some (at least the old-fashioned xdm) don't give the user a choice. But lightdm does follow the general rule.

Comment: Thanks that covers most of it... however I still do not know where lightdm keeps the "current" setting stored.

Comment: @Cheetaiean I think it's `~/.dmrc`. At least [that's the file used for autologin](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/LightDM#Enabling_autologin). On one machine where I use lightdm, that file is present and designates `lightdm-xsession`. I don't remember what it looks like on the GUI and can't check at the moment.

Comment: Yes you are correct, I just verified that. Fascinating stuff.